# CakePHP Ajax : update list with change in related list

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-2.7, cakephp-ajaxhelper

I am working on CakePHP 2.7.8. I want to update related list with change in list using Ajax.

I have a `customers` table and `customer_addresses` table in the database and `customers` and `customerAddress` models in the project.

There is another controller `serviceRequests` where I have to select `customer` and address of the selected customer from a drop down list generated by CakePHP from database.

What I have done-
I have added a function `getCustomerAddress` in the `serviceRequests` controller

```
public function getCustomerAddress(){
            $customer_id = $this->request->data['Post']['customer_id'];

            $customer_address = $this->CustomerAddress->find('list',array(
                'condition' => array('CustomerAddress.customer_id' => $customer_id),
                'recursive' => -1
            ));

            $this->set('customerAddresses', $customer_address);
            $this->layout = 'ajax';
        }
```

to display the retrieved data, I have a view `get_customer_address.ctp`

```
<?php
foreach ($customerAddresses as $key => $value): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $key;?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In the `add.ctp` view of `serviceRequests` controller for `add` function, I have added following script at the last.

```
<div class="serviceRequests form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('ServiceRequest'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Service Request'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('customer_id');
        echo $this->Form->input('customer_address_id');
        echo $this->Form->input('status');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>

<?php
$this->Js->get('#ServiceRequestCustomerId')->event('change',
        $this->Js->request(array(
            'controller' => 'serviceRequests',
            'action' => 'getCustomerAddress'
        ), array(
            'update' => '#ServiceRequestCustomerAddressId',
            'async' => true,
            'method' => 'post',
            'dataExpression' => true,
            'data' => $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
                'isForm' => true,
                'inline' => true
            ))
        ))
        );
?>
```

and to render `Js`, I have added following code to to last of `default.ctp`

```
<!-- script for layout -->
    <?php echo $scripts_for_layout; ?>
    <!-- Js writeBuffer -->
    <?php
    if(class_exists('JsHelper') && method_exists($this->Js, 'writeBuffer')) echo $this->Js->writeBuffer ();
    // writes cached scripts
    ?>
```

But on accessing `localhost/serviceRequests/add` the ajax call is not working and all customer's name and all customer's addresses are showing in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how to implement chained selects with cake http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax_examples/chained_dropdowns
 - the related article for that example is here http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/